# What could cause a SUMPRODUCT formula to return N/As even though it reads the criteria accurately and there are existing values?

Tags: excel-formula

I have F9 inspected every parenthetical and they all return TRUEs from the 2024 Budget Tab where they should, matching the first four digits of the account, in the first parenthetical; the last four digits of the account, in the second; and the date in the 3rd parenthetical. Everything returns a TRUE where it's supposed to. So it's not a matter of making things numbervalue or text, etc... and there are values that match these accounts and dates.

I'm losing my mind. Why might this be returning N/As?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('BUDGET - 2024'!$E$4:$E$502=VALUE(LEFT('Budget Spread'!$K15,4)&"00"))*('BUDGET - 2024'!$BG$2:$HB$2=VALUE(RIGHT('Budget Spread'!$K15,4)))*('BUDGET - 2024'!$BG$3:$HC$3='Budget Spread'!L$14)*'BUDGET - 2024'!$BG$4:$HC$502)
```

[image: Source Table]

[image: Destination Table]

Comment: What happens if you remove `VALUE`?

Comment: Same deal. That value was added to see if it would fix it. neutral result.

Comment: In that case it's likely the months being text in one sheet and dates in the other? Try the conditions individually and you'll find it.